# How to make react child component using conditional

Tags: reactjs

So usually we create child component of react using code seems like this :

```
const component =(<button>Bla Bla</button>)
```

How you can create that using conditional? I have to try this one :

```
const component =(()=>{
if(true){
return(<button>Bla Bla</button>)
}else{
return  null
}
})
```

but that code throw error :  Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

How to write that code properly ?

Comment: Try<div> value && <MyComp/></div> . Value is a state value or something else. You'd use the conditional rendering in your JSX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
const component = true ? (<button>Bla Bla</button>): null
```

`true` can be any conditional you want to check

Answer (score 3):

You can do that by simply passing a `prop` to it. Make the component like:

```
const Button = ({ display }) => {
  return <>
   {display && <button>I am Button<button>} 

  </>
}
```

Now if you want to display it you can just call it as:

```
<Button display={true} />
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    const myComp = ({value}) =>(
      <div>
       {
         value &&
          <myComp />
       }
     <div>
```

From my comment above. One way is to  use conditional rendering in you JSX code

Answer (score 0):

```
const bio = this.state.displayBio ? (
  <div>
    This is true false condition
    <button onClick={this.toggleDisplay}>Show Less</button>
  </div>
) : (
  <div>
    <button onClick={this.toggleDisplay}>Show More</button>
  </div>
);
```